# Problema con XML(diseño) En Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Tengo problemas al visualizar mis objetos en el xml(lado diseño)
Alguien que haya podido resolver esta cuestion.aqui les envio una imagen  con  las fallas que me muestra Android Studio(version 3.0).
Por sierto ya limpie cache de todas esas clases que me muestra ahi y ya hice "rebuild" y "refresh" pero nada de nada. La App funciona bien no tengo errores en otra partes, solo que no me visualiza.
[image]

Comment: ¿Te auto completa o te sale la ayuda a la hora de escribir en el xml?. Si no es así es posible que te falte por implementar alguna librería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás podrías intentar

- Verificar si existe una nueva actualización para android studio
- En el graddle de la app, actualizar el `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` de la `dependencies`
- Cambiar la API Version in Editor, el símbolo de android que está en el layout. Buscar una versión sin problemas.

Este artículo podría servirte

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-
be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575815/the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated-android-support-v7-widget-too)